# Why might "Interactions" tab be missing in component settings in custom aura layout setup?

Tags: aura, page-layout, custom

We need to create our own layout for an app, and we've run into an issue with aura layout.

There isn't much I can find on the subject, since most of the inquiries either lead me to the process of making interactions, or the process of making a custom layout.

The problem is that on any standard aura layout, we get the option to setup our interactions (next to the Properties tab):

[image]

However, in our custom aura Layout, the interactions are simply not there, and we've only the component Properties to setup by default:

[image]

Does anyone know why are "Interactions" missing in the custom layout, and how would we add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while we've come across this piece in the documentation:

[Dynamic Interactions isn't supported on pages based on custom page templates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.dynamic_interactions_limitations.htm&type=5)

Unfortunately, it means that this approach is not possible.